# Strange results when converting rgb <> yuv using ffmpeg in python

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have JPG images and I am trying to do the following:

1. resize the input and save the result into PNG
2. convert PNG images to YUV (for instance yuv444p10le) in AVI container
3. convert AVI back to PNG image.

I am using python 3 and ffmpeg Linux version installed on Colab

I printed the difference between resized_png and restored_png. I have values of 255 which doesn't make sense at all.

```
 [[[  0 255   1]
  [  0   0   1]
  [  0 255   1]
  ...
  [  1   0   0]
  [  1   0   0]
  [  2   0   1]]

 [[  0 255   1]
  [  0 255   1]
  [  1   0   0]
  ...
  [  1   0   0]
  [  1   0   0]
  [  1   0   0]]

 [[  0   0   1]
  [  0   0   1]
  [  0   0   1]
  ...
  [  1 255   0]
  [  1 255   1]
  [  1   0   0]]

 ...

 [[255   0   0]
  [255   0   1]
  [255   0   1]
  ...
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   1]
  [255   0   1]]

 [[255   0   1]
  [255   0   1]
  [255   0   1]
  ...
  [  0   0   1]
  [  0   0   1]
  [  0   0   0]]

 [[255   0   1]
  [255   0   1]
  [255   0   1]
  ...
  [255   1   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   1]]]
```

```
input_image = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/adv_dnn/datasets/im2.jpg'
output_resized = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/adv_dnn/datasets/im2.png'
folder_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/adv_dnn/datasets/'

#do resize
# code = subprocess.call('cd /usr/bin/ffmpeg',  shell=True)
# print(code)
cmd_resize = ['ffmpeg', '-y', '-i',  input_image,'-vf', 'scale=224:224', output_resized]
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd_resize, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate()
print(out)
print(err)

fmt = ['yuv420p', 'yuv420p10le', 'yuv444p', 'yuv444p10le']
for f in fmt:
  cmd2YUV = ['ffmpeg', '-y', '-i', output_resized, '-c:v', 'libx264', '-preset', 'placebo',\
             '-qp', '0', '-x264-params', "keyint=15:no-deblock=1", '-pix_fmt', f, \
             '-sws_flags', 'spline+accurate_rnd+full_chroma_int', \
             '-vf', "colorspace=bt709:iall=bt601-6-625:fast=1", '-color_range', '1', '-colorspace', '1', 
             '-color_primaries', '1', '-color_trc', '1', folder_path+'im2_'+f+'.avi']
  process = subprocess.Popen(cmd2YUV, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  out, err = process.communicate()
  print(out)
  print(err)

  cmd2PNG = ['ffmpeg', '-y', '-i',  folder_path+'im2_'+f+'.avi', '-compression_level', '10', '-pred', 'mixed', \
             '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24', '-sws_flags', '+accurate_rnd+full_chroma_int', \
             folder_path+'im2_'+f+'.png']
  process = subprocess.Popen(cmd2PNG, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  out, err = process.communicate()
  print(out)
  print(err)

im1=pilim.open('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/adv_dnn/datasets/im2.png')
im2=pilim.open('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/adv_dnn/datasets/im2_yuv444p10le.png')
im1_2d = np.asarray(im1)
im2_2d = np.asarray(im2)
print(im2_2d-im1_2d)
```

Comment: What's the reason for doing this? Converting JPG → PNG → YUV (AVI) → PNG seems inefficient.

Comment: I need to introduce some distortion to the rgb image (in YUV) and i want to make sure that is the only source of distortion. i.e. conversion rgb24 <> yuv not introducing any distortion.

Comment: rgb to yuv420 will add distortion.

Comment: Not according to the ffmpeg WIKI. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/colorspace it says that SSIM is 99.98%.

Comment: I tested the above conversion using ffmpegin Windows OS. I got 100%. SSIM. but why i have the above strange result in Linux and python.